# MS Crypto API behavior on Windows XP vs Vista/7

Tags: c++, windows-xp, cryptoapi, mscapi

I'm trying to understand how to get a public key imported from PEM format (sample included in the code below) across XP, Vista and Windows 7.  The sample code will import the key on both XP and Windows Vista/7, but not the same way.

On Windows XP, the string **"(Prototype)"** is required in the cryptographic provider's name, and allows the call to CryptImportPublicKeyInfo to pass.

On Windows 7, the **"(Prototype)"** provider is apparently present, but does not support the call to CryptImportPublicKeyInfo, which is confusing.

What might a correct implementation look like between these operating systems?  Is it necessary to detect XP and request the name with **"(Prototype)"**, and without it for other operating systems?  Is it possible that that will still fail on some XP systems?

Or, is there a way to detect this confusing behavior and select whichever cryptographic provider will support the necessary call?

*Output on Windows 7:*

```
ANALYZING CRYPTOGRAPHIC SUPPORT FOR:
     "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"
     CryptAcquireContext success.
     CryptAcquireContext.1 success.
     CryptStringToBinary.2 success.
     CryptDecodeObjectEx success.
     CryptImportPublicKeyInfo success.
     SUCCESS.
ANALYZING CRYPTOGRAPHIC SUPPORT FOR:
     "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider (Prototype)"
     CryptAcquireContext success.
     CryptAcquireContext.1 success.
     CryptStringToBinary.2 success.
     CryptDecodeObjectEx success.
     CryptImportPublicKeyInfo FAILED****.
```

*Output on Windows XP:*

```
ANALYZING CRYPTOGRAPHIC SUPPORT FOR:
     "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"
     CryptAcquireContext success.
     CryptAcquireContext.1 success.
     CryptStringToBinary.2 success.
     CryptDecodeObjectEx success.
     CryptImportPublicKeyInfo FAILED****.
ANALYZING CRYPTOGRAPHIC SUPPORT FOR:
     "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider (Prototype)"
     CryptAcquireContext success.
     CryptAcquireContext.1 success.
     CryptStringToBinary.2 success.
     CryptDecodeObjectEx success.
     CryptImportPublicKeyInfo success.
     SUCCESS.
```

C++ source code which produces that output: (requires crypt32.lib)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

bool windowsAcquireProviderContext(HCRYPTPROV *pHandleProv, LPCTSTR pProviderName);
bool analyzeCryptographicSupport(LPCTSTR pProviderName);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    analyzeCryptographicSupport(MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV);
    analyzeCryptographicSupport(L"Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider (Prototype)");
    return 0;
}

bool windowsAcquireProviderContext(HCRYPTPROV *pHandleProv, LPCTSTR pProviderName) {
    WCHAR *pContainerName = L"blah blah blah";
    if(!CryptAcquireContext(pHandleProv, pContainerName, pProviderName, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_SILENT)) {
        if(GetLastError() == NTE_BAD_KEYSET) {
            if(CryptAcquireContext(pHandleProv, pContainerName, pProviderName, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET|CRYPT_SILENT)) {
                return true;
            }
        } 
    }
    return true;
}

LPCWSTR pwszPemPublicKey = 
    L"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n"
    L"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC6GUVcbn92bahlwOskKi8XkG9q\r\n"
    L"Vq863+C4cOWC6HzJojc011pJFFIBu8/pG1EI8FZJdBmTrFaJTriYw1/SpbOH0QqE\r\n"
    L"eHanT8qWn+S5m9xgDJoWTBJKcnu3OHOvJJU3c8jOHQQnRWLfghJH4vnwStdiwUUY\r\n"
    L"SMWpwuHObsNelGBgEQIDAQAB\r\n"
    L"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n";
int pemPublicKeySize = wcslen(pwszPemPublicKey);

bool analyzeCryptographicSupport(LPCTSTR pProviderName) {

    printf("ANALYZING CRYPTOGRAPHIC SUPPORT FOR:\r\n");
    wprintf(L"\t \"%s\"\r\n", pProviderName);

    HCRYPTPROV hProv;
    if(!windowsAcquireProviderContext(&hProv, pProviderName)) {
        wprintf(L"\t CryptAcquireContext FAILED.\r\n");
        return false;
    }
    wprintf(L"\t CryptAcquireContext success.\r\n");

    DWORD blobSize;

    if(!CryptStringToBinary(pwszPemPublicKey, pemPublicKeySize, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64_ANY,  NULL, &blobSize, NULL, NULL)) {
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        wprintf(L"\t CryptStringToBinary.1 FAILED****.\r\n");
        return false;
    }
    wprintf(L"\t CryptAcquireContext.1 success.\r\n");

    BYTE *pBlob = (BYTE *)malloc(blobSize);

    if(!CryptStringToBinary(pwszPemPublicKey, pemPublicKeySize, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64_ANY,  pBlob, &blobSize, NULL, NULL)) {
        free(pBlob);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        wprintf(L"\t CryptStringToBinary.2 FAILED****.\r\n");
        return false;
    }
    wprintf(L"\t CryptStringToBinary.2 success.\r\n");

    CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO *publicKeyInfo;
    DWORD publicKeyInfoLen;
    HCRYPTKEY hPublicKey;

    if(!CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO, pBlob, blobSize, CRYPT_DECODE_ALLOC_FLAG, NULL, &publicKeyInfo, &publicKeyInfoLen)) {
        free(pBlob);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        wprintf(L"\t CryptDecodeObjectEx FAILED****.\r\n");
        return false;
    }
    wprintf(L"\t CryptDecodeObjectEx success.\r\n");

    if(!CryptImportPublicKeyInfo(hProv, X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, publicKeyInfo, &hPublicKey)) {
        LocalFree(publicKeyInfo);
        free(pBlob);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        wprintf(L"\t CryptImportPublicKeyInfo FAILED****.\r\n");
        return false;
    }
    wprintf(L"\t CryptImportPublicKeyInfo success.\r\n");

    CryptDestroyKey(hPublicKey);
    LocalFree(publicKeyInfo);
    free(pBlob);
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);

    wprintf(L"\t SUCCESS.\r\n");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason of the problem which you describes is very easy: **Microsoft renamed AES Cryptographic Provider** from

- `"Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider (Prototype)"` in Windows XP to
- `"Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"` in the later versions of the operation systems.

In `WinCrypt.h` are defined the corresponding constants as `MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV` and `MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV_XP` which you can use.

If you don't want to test the version of the operation system you can just use [CryptAcquireContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379886%28VS.85%29.aspx) with `NULL` as `pszProvider` (and continue to use `PROV_RSA_AES` as the `dwProvType`). In your code you can include `analyzeCryptographicSupport(NULL);`.

You can also examine the "Name" value of the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider Types\Type 024
```

to see the name of the default `PROV_RSA_AES` provider.

Comment: Looks the the short answer for my case is to detect XP and use the appropriate provider string... unfortunate, but not a very big deal.

Comment: @g01d, that works well, but the more "correct" way is to detect not OS version, but the crypto name in the registry and handle if from there. Splitting hairs, I know...

Comment: @Prof.Falken: Of cause one can detect the OS. I wrote that one can use `pszProvider=NULL` and `dwProvType=PROV_RSA_AES` alternatively. I tried *to explain* in my answer that the real origin of the problem is the usage `MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV` constant which is just the string from the registry. I suppose that Microsoft made just an error in Windows XP with usage of wrong text with unneeded " (Prototype)" suffix in the registry. So one "fixed" the error by introduction of `MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV_XP`. If one understand **the reason** of the problem one can choose the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember reading somewhere that Microsoft goofed up on the name and it requires "(Prototype)" to be present on XP and absent on Vista and above.  I think you will have to detect the platform at runtime and use the appropriate string.