# CryptAcquireContext ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER on NT Service

Tags: c++, winapi, service, cryptoapi

I have a Windows service written in C++, which uses:

```
CryptAcquireContext( &hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL,0);
```

I keep getting **ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER** although the same line of code works perfectly if i use it in a user mode application.

Note: I've already tried with no luck:

```
CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET | CRYPT_SILENT
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9794821/1517648 ?

Comment: yep, still getting the same error ...