# Make CNG crypto API work on Windows XP?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, windows-xp, cng

Is there a way to get the [Microsoft Cryptography API: Next Generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to work on Windows XP?

Comment: MS Crypto API behavior on Windows XP vs Vista/7

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495247/ms-crypto-api-behavior-on-windows-xp-vs-vista-7

Comment: @LukeCodeBaker, I don't think that has much to do with CNG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not. CNG is available on Windows Vista+ only. KSP is not the only dependency that CNG has. There are several other functionalities for which it requires the underlying OS to be Vista+.

Answer (score -1):

As you certainly already know, CNG rely on a windows vista/seven/8 CNG keyisolation service (keyiso) it's provided by the operating system and not available in XP.
 You can rely on cryptoAPI which is availaible in XP. It will certainly be cheaper to provide win 7/8 licence than to try to redevelop the service and to port the SDK for XP which was a nice OS but not the future.

Comment: I know it's impossible to give windows licences, but customers can't always have old computer and to notch functionality.